# Use of Nested enums appropriate in this case?

Tags: java, design-patterns, enums

I have a requirement to support a number of `ChartTypes`. Each of these chart types can support a number of `ChartSubTypes`. For example `AreaChart` type can have `PercentArea`, `StackedArea` etc. I am thinking of using an Enum both for `ChartTypes` and `SubTypes` and then maintain a map somewhere which will be something like :

```
Map<ChartType,List<ChartSubTypes> mapTypes;
```

Can I somehow use a nested enum pattern here? If yes then how?

Comment: `AreaChart`, `PercentArea` etc., are also enums?

Comment: @MouseEvent yes they are also constants

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to model them as classes and use inheritance? Maybe you're adding more charts later that you don't know now?

Comment: @keuleJ an enum works best for a requirements where a limited hardcoded set is needed. If a chart type IS one or more sub chart types I still wouldn't use inheritance, but would probably use composition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If that definition is constant (i.e. You know which sub types can contain every type) You can use here enum definitions as follows

```
enum ChartSubTypes{
    PercentArea, StackedArea, ChartSubType3;
}

enum ChartTypes{
    AreaChart(ChartSubTypes.PercentArea, ChartSubTypes.StackedArea), 
    CharType2(ChartSubTypes.PercentArea, ChartSubTypes.ChartSubType3);

    private List<ChartSubTypes> subTypes = new ArrayList<ChartSubTypes>();

    private ChartTypes(ChartSubTypes ...chartSubTypes){
        for(ChartSubTypes subType : chartSubTypes){
            subTypes.add(subType);
        }
    }

    public List<ChartSubTypes> getSubTypes(){
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(subTypes);
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can add the chart sub types to the chart type like thus:

```
public enum ChartType {
    AreaChart(SubChartType.PercentArea, SubChartType.StackedArea), 
    AnotherChart(SubChartType.PercentArea);

    private List<SubChartType> subChartTypes = new ArrayList<>();

    ChartType(SubChartType... subChartTypes) {
        Collections.addAll(this.subChartTypes, subChartTypes);
    } 

    public List<SubChartType> getSubChartTypes() {
        return this.subChartTypes;
    }

    public static Map<ChartType,List<SubChartType>> getMapTypes() {
        HashMap<ChartType,List<SubChartType>> mapTypes = new HashMap<>();
        for (ChartType chartType : values()) {
            mapTypes.put(chartType, chartType.getSubChartTypes());
        }
        return mapTypes;
    }
}
```

To get the map you wanted simply call `ChartType.getMapTypes();`.

If the requirement is that each ChartType should have one or more SubChartTypes then you will need this constructor to enforce that requirement.

```
ChartType(SubChartType requiredSubType, SubChartType... subChartTypes) {
    this.subChartTypes.add(requiredSubType);
    Collections.addAll(this.subChartTypes, subChartTypes);
}
```

Varargs can have zero arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Use interfaces, to group enum types:

```
public interface ChartType {
    public someCommonMethod();
}

public enum AreaChart extends ChartType{
    PercentArea {
        public someCommonMethod(){
            //your code here
        }
    }, 
    StackedArea {
        public someCommonMethod(){
            //your code here
        }
    };
}
```

You can of course contain multiple implementations of that interface, even if you don't know of it yet. You can use the interface as a parameter (generic or method argument) type, too.