# define subtype for one item of an enum in java

Tags: java, enums

I have an enum that contains these three types of an area in a street:

```
public enum EArea
{
    VEHICLE_WAY,
    SIDEWALK,
    FORBIDDEN
}
```

I would like to define two subtype for a `VEHICLE_WAY`. For example `DIRECT_LANE` and `TURNLEFT_LANE`.

I thought maybe I can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15288630/use-of-nested-enums-appropriate-in-this-case) and define subtypes, but just the `VEHICLE_WAY` has subtypes. any better idea to do this in java?

Comment: Why not have it like; `DIRECT_VEHICLE_WAY`, `TURNLEFT_VEHICLE_WAY`, more simple if there is no strict requirement for the original three. Since only one of the enum has subtype, not all, I'd not use another enum just for that.

Comment: That doesn't sound a good architecture for me. I would like to have just these three type. The cars allowed to be on `VEHICLE_WAY`, the pedestrians on `SIDEWALK` and neigther of them on `FORBIDDEN` area.

Comment: If you insist on using enums, then you would actually have an enumeration with values `[SIDEWALK, FORBIDDEN, DIRECT_LANE, TURNLEFT_LANE]`, and you should define other rules by defining methods in enumeration, such as `boolean allowsVehicles()` or `boolean allowPedestrians()`.

Comment: Can you accept an answer? Let's conclude this question!

Answer (score 1):

I would advise not to use enums this way. A better approach would be to create classes from your enum values and extend the `VEHICLE_WAY` class into the sub-types you want. Also the enum value `FORBIDDEN` sounds more like a property.

```
public class VehicleWay {
   ...
}

public class DirectLane extends VehicleWay {
   ...
}

public class TurnLeftLane extends VehicleWay {
   ...
}

public class SideWalk {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize the following class with a nested subtype enum, however the subtype is somewhat hidden, you can continue working with a single enum;

```
enum EArea {
    VEHICLE_WAY, SIDEWALK, FORBIDDEN;

    Lane lane;

    public Lane getLane() {
        return lane;
    }

    public EArea setLane(Lane lane) {
        this.lane = lane;
        return this;
    }

    enum Lane {
        DIRECT_LANE, TURNLEFT_LANE
    }
}
```

Then you can use the subtypes like;

```
EArea.VEHICLE_WAY.setLane(EArea.Lane.DIRECT_LANE);     // returns a direct lane vehicle way
EArea.VEHICLE_WAY.setLane(EArea.Lane.TURNLEFT_LANE);   // returns a turnleft lane vehicle way
```

Though this allows addition of lane to other enums, so you can validate within getter/setters if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an interface `EArea` and have multiple enums implement it.

Comment: I'm afraid that you don't understand my question. But thank you!

Comment: There is no way to implement nested enums in Java, so this should be your next easiest method.
You could have `public enum VehicleWay implements EArea` and then maybe `public enum OtherArea implements EArea`